# How to find the average of a distinct value based on a count in adjacent column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to find the average "DAYS_FROM_OPN_2_CALL" based on the "TOTAL_CALLS" column.

I'm assuming theirs a fairly simple way to do this that I'm overlooking

My data set looks like this ;

Header 1 = days to open (eg. 1,2,3,4,5) - Header2= total calls (eg., 523,469,1020,234,675)

[image]

Comment: How is your "data set" related to screenshot you posted (I guess that's desired output)?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to find the average "DAYS_FROM_OPN_2_CALL" based on the "TOTAL_CALLS" column.

`GROUP BY` the `total_calls` and then use the `AVG` aggregation function to get the average `DAYS_FROM_OPN_2_CALL`:

```sql
SELECT total_calls,
       AVG(DAYS_FROM_OPN_2_CALL) AS avg_days_from_opn_2_call
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY total_calls;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (days_from_opn_2_call, total_calls) AS
SELECT -115, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT -111, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT -110, 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT -109, 9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT -108, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT -107, 3 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | TOTAL_CALLS | AVG_DAYS_FROM_OPN_2_CALL |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2 | -115 |
> | 1 | -109.5 |
> | 5 | -110 |
> | 9 | -109 |
> | 3 | -107 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=031d5d5c1d1ab3cd6c9baf8756a3cc7e)*